# <form:option> default value

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have following spring-mvc code in jsp page

```
<form:select path="role" id="idRole" >
    <form:option value="">Select a message role</form:option>
    <form:options items="${roles}" />
</form:select>
```

In Java class here is model attribute:

```
@ModelAttribute("role")
public Role[] roles() {
    return Role.values();
}
```

The Values are: A, B, C, D.

**We need to have "C" value in option form already by default!**

When the user go to this page, he see pre-defined C value in option, and of course if he wants to change it - he changes to A, B and etc. What should i do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280611/spring-mvc-formoptions-default-value

Comment: hmm..but what was changed? i have the same code in this case

Comment: d'u mean if i use for example "C" as path name, it is able to work?

Comment: sorry, Shreyos, it's not working.. Spring MVC looks for appropriate bean name and after that looking for valid getter/setter method. So as a result we have NotReadablePropertyException

Comment: Right now, the default value is `Select a message role`. You want to change it to `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would set the value of the "role" in your ModelAttribute to "C" prior to displaying the form.  When Spring MVC renders the page, it will select the proper value.

Comment: How can you provide this value when you actually have an enum class.

Comment: public enum Role { A, B, C, D}

Comment: Are you not using a ModelAttribute as a Command Object/Form Bean?  Typically you would have a bean that represents your "form", and you would have a value in it that is a "Role" representing the user's choice.  How are you passing the user's choice back to the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

If Suppose Your Model is OBJABC

```
class OBJABC {

private String abc;
private ENUMABC enumABC;

...Getters and Setters.....

}
```

and it is having enum ENUMABC

```
public enum ENUMABC 
{


    A("A"),

    B("B"),

    C("C");


    private String value;


    private ENUMABC (String val)
    {
        value = val;
    }


    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }


}
```

So if you are setting your passing model when loading form

You can write

```
OBJABC obj = new OBJABC ();
obj.setEnumABC(ENUMABC.B);

model.addAttribute("modelAttribute",obj );
```

in controller

on jsp you should set same key as a model attribute

Answer (score 0):

@CodeChimp's' answer is correct. Your model should contain the user's choice from the list of Roles. But the list, and the choice, are separate.

Your model containing the choice could look something like this:

```
public class RoleModel {

    private Role role;

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }
}
```

So in your controller you'd have:

```
@ModelAttribute("roleModel")
public RoleModel createModel() {
    return new RoleModel();
}
```

And:

```
@ModelAttribute("roles")
public Role[] getRoles() {
    return Role.values();
}
```

So the `path="role"` on your `<form:select>` tag in your JSP maps to the role property in the `RoleModel`. Whereas list of roles for the select options comes from the `roles` model attribute.

You'd also need to register a custom PropertyEditor that knew how to convert a String 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' to the Role enum instance. There's a post [here](https://numberformat.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/spring-mvc-form-validation-with-customproperty-editors/) that describes custom property editors.